# How to do resize to image before upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, image-uploading, image-resizing

I want to resize my images before I upload them to s3 amazon.
I need 3 diffrent size : resizing (original image, thumbnail, web size) .
How can I do this?
How do I get the path of my image that was past with method POST?

This is my code:(to upload image to s3 amazon with node js)

```
 app.post('/upload', function(request, response) {
    var ext
      , hash
      , form = new formidable.IncomingForm()
      , files = []
      , fields = [];
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.uploadDir = 'tmp';
    form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
      ext = file.path.split('.')[1];
      hash = hasher();
      file.path = form.uploadDir + '/' + hash;
    });
    form.on('field', function(field, value) {
      fields.push([field, value]);
    }).on('file', function(field, file) {
      files.push([field, file]);
    }).on('end', function() {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../tmp/' + hash, function(error, buf) {
        var req = client.put('/images/' + hash + '.png', {
          'x-amz-acl': 'private',
          'Content-Length': buf.length,
          'Content-Type': 'image/png'
        });
        req.on('response', function(res){
          var image = new S3({
            hash : hash,
            url : req.url
          });
          image.save(function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.error(error);
            } else {
              response.redirect('http://' + request.headers.host + '/' + hash);
            };
          })
        });
        req.end(buf);
      });
    });
    form.parse(request);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use graphicsmagick, imagemagick for that. Also **gm** module. [Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)

Example:

```
gm(buf)
.resize(100, 100)
.toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) {
  if (err) return handle(err);
  console.log('done!');
upload(buffer,function(err){
if(!err)
console.log("uploaded")
 }
}) //use buffer for upload

function upload(buffer,callback){
s3bucket = new AWS.S3();
params={
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: folder + '/' + fileName,
    Body: buffer,
    ACL: 'public-read'
}
s3bucket.putObject(params,function(err)....
}
```

Comment: ok I download everything and now where I need to put this code in my code?

Comment: just after file buffer/stream is created, check the streams and buffer methods of gm module just pass the stream/buffer and eventually converted image's stream/buffer will be returned use that to upload to s3 bucket

Comment: It dosent work to me. The image is in the same size like before

Comment: i tried changing my example maybe now, u'll get that

Answer (score 0):

HTML component:

```
*<*input type="file" class="hidden" id="logoFile">// remove *
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
file = document.getElementById('logoFile').files[0];    
image = new Parse.File("image.jpg", file); // I am using Parse. You can use other Node.js modules.
```

You can set size as per your wish.

Try this:

```
image.resize(200, 200, function(err, image){
    // encode resized image to jpeg and get a Buffer object
    image.toBuffer('jpg', function(err, buffer){
    // save buffer to disk / send over network / etc.
   });
});
```

Comment: from where you get the "image">?